# If $f(z)$ is entire and satisfying the condition $f(z_1+z_2)=f(z_1)f(z_2) \exists c\in C$ such that $f(z)=e^{cz}$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is entire and satisfying the condition $f(z_1+ z_2)=f(z_1) f(z_2) \exists c\in C$ such that $f(z)=e^{cz}$

I started complex analysis very recently
How to prove this? I am not able to get any clue.

I thought in following lines

Take $g(z)=e^{-cz} f(z)$

$g'(z)=-ce^{-cz}f(z)+e^{-cz} f'(z)$

Again $f'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$

I am not able to get $f(z_1 +z_2) = f(z_1)f(z_2)$ to explore further...

Comment: My guess is that you meant to write that $f(z_1+z_2)=f(z_1)f(z_2)$. Obviously, **no** function of the type $z\mapsto e^{cz}$ has that property, unless $c=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume $f(z+z')+f(z)f(z')$. Remark that $f(0.0)=f(0)^2$ implies that $f(0)=1$ or $f(0)=0$, if $f(0)=0, f(0+z)=f(0)f(z)=0$ and $f=0$. Suppose that $f\neq 0$. Write $c=f'(z)$

$f'(z)=lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{{f(z+h)-f(z)}\over h}=f(z)lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{{f(h)-1}\over h}=cf(z)$.  consider $g(z)=e^{-cz}f(z)$, show that $g'(z)=-ce^{-z}f(z)+e^{-z}cf(z)=0$. This implies that $g$ is constant and $g(z)=g(0)=1$. We deduce that $f(z)=e^{cz}$.

Comment: Qn says $f(z_1 z_2) = f(z_1)f(z_2)$ It was asked in a previous year Qn asked in competetive exam related to maths.

Comment: $e^{cz_1z_2}\neq e^{cz_1}e^{cz_2}$ if $c\neq 0$. For example, if $n_1,n_2$ are positive integers, $e^{n_1n_2}={(e^{n_1}})^{n_2}$.

Comment: thank you. Should i delete this Qn?

Comment: You can correct it too.